# Help understanding why I am getting an error when calling the observe() function on IUniswapV3Pool?

Tags: ethers.js, hardhat, uniswap, abi, uniswapv3

The function I'm trying to call is observe() at line 326

I have previously successfully called this before but I'm coming back to it after a while and it is giving an error I don't understand. This is the code I'm using:

```
const ethers = require('ethers');
const Big = require('big.js');
const CC = require('./common_code');
const addr_bk = require('./address_book');
const ABI = require('./abi/IUniswapV3Pool.json');
const fs = require('fs');
const prompt = require('prompt-sync')({sigint: true});


// get pair address and node address
const pair_req = prompt('Which pair would you like to track? ');
const FILE_NAME = pair_req.replace('/', '-')
const FEE = prompt('Set fee level: ("3000" or "500") ');
const POOL = addr_bk.address_book['main'][FEE][pair_req];
const PROVIDER = CC.PROVIDER;

// Initiate contract to interact with
const POOL_CONTRACT = new ethers.Contract(POOL, ABI.abi, PROVIDER);

// Function to calculate exchange rate of a liquidity pool
async function exchangeRate() {
        [reserve_token1, reserve_token2] = await CC.fetchReserves(POOL_CONTRACT);
        price = reserve_token2.div(reserve_token1);
        switch (pair_req) {
                case 'usdc/jpyc':
                        priceToWrite = String(price.toNumber() / 10 ** 12);
                        break;
                case 'wbtc/dai':
                        priceToWrite = String(price.toNumber() / 10 ** 10);
                        break;
                default:
                        priceToWrite = String(price.toNumber() / 10 ** 18);
           };
        //console.log(priceToWrite);
        return priceToWrite;
}


// Function to build OHLC data for specified pairs
async function priceScraper() {
        fs.writeFile(`data/${FILE_NAME}.csv`, 'Date,Open,High,Low,Close\n', err => {
                if (err) {
                        console.error(err);
                }
        });
        while (true) {
                var date = Date.now()
                var open = 0.0;
                var high = 0.0;
                var low = 0.0;
                var close = 0.0;
                for (var x = 0; x < 60; x++) {
                        let rate = await POOL_CONTRACT.functions.observe([3600, 0]);
                        /* console.log(rate); */
                        console.log(Big(rate.tickCumulatives[0]).toFixed(2), Big(rate.tickCumulatives[1]).toFixed(2));
                        /* let rate = await exchangeRate(); */
                        console.log(`date = ${date}, x = ${x}, rate = ${rate}`);
                        /* if (x === 0) {open = rate; low = rate;} */
                        /* if (x === 59) {close = rate;} */
                        /* if (rate > high) {high = rate;} */
                        /* if (rate < low) {low = rate;} */
                        await CC.sleep(60000)
                }
                fs.appendFile(`data/${FILE_NAME}.csv`, `${date},${open},${high},${low},${close}\n`, err => {
                        if (err) {
                                console.error(err);
                        }
                });
        }
}


priceScraper();
```

This is just supposed to build a candlestick based on price data pulled in by the observe function. Problem is the observe function is throwing the following error:

```
/home/$USER/Nextcloud/Programming/Candlestick_Maker/node_modules/ethers/lib.commonjs/utils/errors.js:114
            error = new TypeError(message);
                    ^

TypeError: no matching function (argument="key", value="functions", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=6.1.0)
    at makeError (/home/$USER/Nextcloud/Programming/Candlestick_Maker/node_modules/ethers/lib.commonjs/utils/errors.js:114:21)
    at assert (/home/$USER/Nextcloud/Programming/Candlestick_Maker/node_modules/ethers/lib.commonjs/utils/errors.js:138:15)
    at assertArgument (/home/$USER/Nextcloud/Programming/Candlestick_Maker/node_modules/ethers/lib.commonjs/utils/errors.js:150:5)
    at Interface.getFunctionName (/home/$USER/Nextcloud/Programming/Candlestick_Maker/node_modules/ethers/lib.commonjs/abi/interface.js:337:39)
    at new WrappedMethod (/home/$USER/Nextcloud/Programming/Candlestick_Maker/node_modules/ethers/lib.commonjs/contract/contract.js:175:38)
    at Contract.getFunction (/home/$USER/Nextcloud/Programming/Candlestick_Maker/node_modules/ethers/lib.commonjs/contract/contract.js:624:17)
    at Object.get (/home/$USER/Nextcloud/Programming/Candlestick_Maker/node_modules/ethers/lib.commonjs/contract/contract.js:565:39)
    at priceScraper (/home/$USER/Nextcloud/Programming/Candlestick_Maker/candle_maker.js:53:35)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/$USER/Nextcloud/Programming/Candlestick_Maker/candle_maker.js:73:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14) {
  code: 'INVALID_ARGUMENT',
  argument: 'key',
  value: 'functions'
}
```

According to the abi:

```
"name": "observe",
      "outputs": [
        {
          "internalType": "int56[]",
          "name": "tickCumulatives",
          "type": "int56[]"
        },
        {
          "internalType": "uint160[]",
          "name": "secondsPerLiquidityCumulativeX128s",
          "type": "uint160[]"
        }
      ],
      "stateMutability": "view",
      "type": "function"
    },
    {
      "inputs": [
        {
          "internalType": "bytes32",
          "name": "key",
          "type": "bytes32"
        }
      ],
```

The type of "key" is bytes32. But if I pull up the contract on github it says the argument is of type: uint32[]. I passed it [3600, 0]. Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

I wonder if I just have the wrong abi, but I do not remember how to get an abi from a contract. In the past I believe I downloaded the .sol file via npm and then compiled with hardhat and it saves the .json in a directory (can't remember which one). Is that the correct way to get the abi or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `POOL_CONTRACT.observe(...)` instead of `POOL_CONTRACT.functions.observe(...)`?

Comment: Wow yes!! it is